# XMLUnit - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, xmlunit

I just downloaded XMLUnit (https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit/releases) but can't get it to work.

When I tried to configure some properties like:

```
        XMLUnit.setControlParser("org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl");
        XMLUnit.setTestParser("org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl");
        XMLUnit.setSAXParserFactory("org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl");
        XMLUnit.setTransformerFactory("org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl");
```

... the follow exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit
at org.jboss.mx.loading.LoadMgr3.beginLoadTask(LoadMgr3.java:212)
at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassImpl(RepositoryClassLoader.java:521)
```

Anyone else had this same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using a jboss application server. I think you just did not include all libraries in you jar / war / ear file.

Comment: Yes, I'm using JBoss. I added all the jars of the downloaded zip file to the build path of my project.

Comment: But do you also deploy the file? Within your IDE it may be in the classpath, but at the application server it may not.